# PayPal Payment Data Transfer "Return URL" in Sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox

The instructions for setting up Payment Data Transfer (PDT) among [PayPal's Developer documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/) speak about configuring a **Return URL**:

> ...This information is sent to the Return URL you specified in your PayPal account profile

Further down the page it gives more information about how to configure a "Return URL" for a PayPal account, but I can't find any correspondence with the user interface for my **Sandbox** account (or any of my "Sandbox Test Accounts").

When I select the Profile page for one of my (business) *Sandbox Test Accounts* there are four tabs of options available:

- Profile
- API Credentials
- Funding
- Settings

...none of these list a "Return URL" field.

Does anyone know where this field may be found?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: adding screenshot of Sandbox PayPal account page and Profile drop-down menu (all items in the drop-down menu return navigation to the same page shown in the screenshot!)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to:

```
1. go to sandbox.paypal.com
2. log in using one of your testing accounts
3. Under profile select "My Selling tools"
4. In "Website preferences" click "update"
5. Here you can set the Return URL
```

(this is probably the url to access after you log in: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments

For live accounts is basically the same process.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, that got me a lot further than I've managed so far! I'm not sure whether I've missed a configuration setting somewhere along the line, but oddly the "My Selling tools" item doesn't appear under my profile menu (screenshot below - hopefully). Oh, I can't add a screenshot to a reply. Uhm... I'll update my original question, sorry about that.

Comment: I guess your test account type should be set to "Business", not "Personal". Anyway, if you log in using your test account and then you click the link I gave you it should take you to the page where you can set the Return URL.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and again, I expect I'll find my way there in the end. Appreciate your help

Comment: Update: yes, that works perfectly! My apologies, I was convinced that I was logging in with a Sandbox account that had been "upgraded" to **Business**, but I was wrong - it was a **Personal** account. Having now tried again with a Business account, I can see this option. Grateful to you.